How not to re-render the canvas once state changes?
I have couple of states where I change on different parts of the project:
which are:
    const [sketchDimensions, setSketchDimensions] = useState(SHOE_DIMENSIONS);
    const [selectedSegment, setSelectedSegment] = useState(null);
    const [activeSidebar, setActiveSidebar] = useState(1);
    
    // and so on 

and I'm using @P5-wrapper/react as a p5 wrapper.
I have a canvas component:
const Canvas = memo(({ sketchDimensions, setSketchDimensions, selectedSegment, setSelectedSegment, activeSidebar, selectedView, currentView }) => {
    if (sketchDimensions.length > 0) {
        console.log('initialized canvas');

        return (
            <ReactP5Wrapper
                sketch={shoeSketch}
                sketchDimensions={sketchDimensions}
                setSketchDimensions={setSketchDimensions}
                selectedSegment={selectedSegment}
                setSelectedSegment={setSelectedSegment}
                // and others
            />
        );
    }
});

I have updateWithProps like following:
    p5.updateWithProps = props => {
        if (props.sketchDimensions !== dataDimensions) {
            dataDimensions = props.sketchDimensions;
        }
        if (props.setSketchDimensions !== setDataDimensions) {
            setDataDimensions = props.setSketchDimensions;
        }

        if (props.selectedSegment !== initVariables.selectedSegment) {
            initVariables.selectedSegment = props.selectedSegment;
        }
    };

and problem appears when the state changes and it creates new canvas elements and GPU increases around 0.8-0.9GB every time one of the states change.

is it possible not to re-render the canvas every time state changes?

Please share a [mcve] instead of little chunks of unrunnable code. Too much is left to the imagination here. Thanks.

@ggorlen thank you for your reply. Is it okay to share codesandbox link here? I'm not quite sure how I would be able to create snippet here with wrapper I'm using.

Preferably all code is in the question itself. No need to make it a runnable snippet, just a package.json and text code blocks I can paste into my local env, hit run, and see the problem. Thanks!

According to devs, it seems to be wrapper's behaviour, so I had to change the logic a bit.
In ThreeJS there is a renderer.forceContextLoss which actually prevents to have too many contents (for more information check here) and in p5 we can use .remove() function.
Additionally, as in our case sketchDimensions and other states change and with the wrapper it redraws and adds to GPU, we had to change the logic to use  functions for specific parts.
Like:
export const changeActiveSidebar = (activeSidebar) => {
    initVariables.activeSidebar = activeSidebar;
}

with this method it does not recreate the canvas (might sound weird, but it indeed works).
